# in next.js, Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I use next.js with ssr,I got server error :

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
[image]

and in my _document.js, my code like this:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {

  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        })
      const props = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...props,
        styles: (
          <>
            {props.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }

  // 如果要重写render 就必须按照这个结构来写
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

how can I do...?

Comment: You are probably rendering object with key value, make sure to get value of object or if you have array then use .map

Answer (score 2):

my problem was I was exporting a page as an async function, when it should have been a regular function.

bad:

```
async function MyPage(props) {
```

good:

```
function MyPage(props) {
```

Answer (score 0):

check your header, and the variables inside the components. debug all the variables rendered within it.

if there is any object rendered.. then that is the issue. you can only render a list not an object with key and value